# Custom Workflow for approve reject functionalities

Tags: 2013

I have requirement and need to know the best solution : I have folders in a document library and the permissions are broken for each folder . 
i.e TestA folder will have a permissions only for group TestA users and 
TestB folder will have group TestB users.

When a documents gets loaded by L1 user into a document library folder TestA , an email needs to be sent  to L2 users (TestA group users only) for approval .

a)L2 can rejects it needs to send back email to L1  OR

b)L2 can reject and send email to "L3" users(group) OR

c)L2 can approve and send approved email back to L1.

Totally 3 radio buttons (Approved,Rejected,rejected to L3)

How can i achieve this , using workflow ? or 
Override with Create custom buttom for "approve/reject" with the 3 fields and handle using code ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a SharePoint 2013 workflow with stages

Use an approval process action in SharePoint Designer, add custom task outcomes, based on those outcomes go to different stages for your A, B, and C.